# Different version of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Show that $$\|AC\|_2 \leq \|A\|_2 \|C\|_2,$$

where $$A, C$$ are square matrices of the same size.

---

I understand this probably needs to use Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but I don't know how should I start the problem, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\|AC\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|ACx\|\le \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A\|\|Cx\|=\|A\|\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Cx\|=\|A\|\|C\|.
$$
Here we only used that
$$
\|ACx\|\le \|A\|\|Cx\|
$$
which is an implication of the definition of $\|A\|$.

Note. This inequality HAS NOTHING TO DO with Cauchy-Schwarz, although it looks the same!

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on your definition of $\|\cdot \|_2$.

In the case of the [induced $2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms). The answer is given by Yiorgos S. Smyrlis.

In the case of the ["entrywise" $2$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms), we see that
\begin{align}
\|AC\|_2^2 =&\ \sum^n_{j=1}\sum^n_{i=1}|(AC)_{ij}|^2 =\sum^n_{j=1}\sum^n_{i=1}\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}c_{kj} \right|^2\\
\leq&\ \sum^n_{j=1}\sum^n_{i=1} \left(\sum^n_{k=1}|a_{ik}|^2 \right)\left(\sum^n_{k=1}|c_{kj}|^2 \right)\\
=&\ \left(\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{k=1}|a_{ik}|^2\right)\left(\sum^n_{j=1}\sum^n_{k=1}|c_{kj}|^2\right) = \|A\|_2^2\|C\|_2^2
\end{align}
which we used Cauchy-Schwarz.